# How do I send a message to ALL text channels with Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send a message (let's say "Hello") to every single channel on my server. I expect it to lag a little bit, since (afaik) there's a limitation of ~5 messages/3 seconds, but still it would be easier to wait than to manually send the message to each channel.

Cannot really figure out if it's even possible to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You con use a combination of the coroutine `await client.send_message(channel, message)` and `client.get_all_channels()`. YOu can also check if you have the permission to send a message to the channel with `Channel.permissions_for(member)`. If you need more information, take a look the the [API reference](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

It may look something like:

```
async def send_all(message, member):
    for channel in client.get_all_channels()
        if channel.permissions_for(member):
             await client.send_message(channel, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. If you are using "bot" instead of "client",
you can try this code:

```python
@bot.command()
async def send_all(message, member):
channels = bot.get_all_channels()
    for channel in channels()
        if channel.permissions_for(member):
             await bot.send_message(channel, message)
```

This might not work, but you shold try. I hope I helped you :)