# spam command spams only one channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My spam command can only spam in one channel, but I need it to spam in all channels. I searched for how to do this, but I did not find answers on any forums

Here is the code

```
i = 100
spam = 0
SKIP_BOTS = False
t = 0

@client.command()
async def spamdef(ctx):

    count = 100
    
    while count > 0:
        
        count -= 1
        
        await ctx.send(text)
```

Who knows what needs to be done to make the bot spam in all channels using the command?

Comment: This breaks Discord ToS.

Comment: I just want to warn you about that. If Discord knows, they can ban you.

Answer (score 0):

```
await ctx.send(text)
```

Here `ctx` represents the **c**on**t**e**x**t in which the message was sent, so you are performing `.send()` only in that specific channel.

---

You may want to do it iterating over a `list` of the `id`s of the channels, and then to fetch the channels from their id.

Otherwise you can simply use the [`client.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.guilds) `list`, and iterate over its [`channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.channels) attribute:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.send(text)
```

---

The easier answer (suggested above) may be found [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881606/how-do-i-send-a-message-to-all-text-channels-with-discord-py), but the code is synchronous, so it may take long to send the message to all the channels.

A faster (and asynchronous) solution would be to use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) in a way similar to this:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    for channel in guild.channels:
        channels.append(channel)
await asyncio.gather(channel.send(text) for channel in channels)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243974/discussion-on-answer-by-flak-zoso-spam-command-spams-only-one-channel).